# Filter Array Object by type and compare key value against Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am stuck a bit here and looking for a possible simple solution to this.

I have an object like below

```
personObj  = { catname: "somecat" ,catname2: "somecat", dogname: "ruff", horsename: "sam"};
```

and then `arrayObject` like

```
personArr = [
  { key: "a1", value: "catname" type: "cat" },
  { key: "a2", value: "catname2", type: "cat" },
  { key: "a3", value: "somedog" type: "dog" },
  { key: "a4", value: "horsename" type : "horse }
];
```

How can I create a function to filter all values by `type` in `personArr` and then check to see if any `personObj` Key matches a `personArr` value and if so return `boolean`?

```
filterAndCheckMatchedObj('cat', personObj) {

  //logic 

  // Filtered by cat  2 matches (catname and catname2) 

  return true
}
```

I am using Angular 4 and Ionic

Does this even make sense? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: not a valid JSON -> `personArr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var personObj  = { catname: "somecat" ,catname2: "somecat", dogname: "ruff", horsename: "sam"}

var personArr  = [{"key":"a1","value":"catname","type":"cat"},{"key":"a2","value":"catname2","type":"cat"},{"key":"a3","value":"somedog","type":"dog"},{"key":"a4","value":"horsename","type":"horse"}];

function find(type, personObj){
  return personArr.filter(item=>item.type === type).filter(item=>(item.value in personObj)).length !== 0
}

console.log(find('cat', personObj))
```

Comment: How about `return personArr.some(item => item.type === type && (item.value in personObj));`

Answer (score 1):

In order to filter parsonArr, you need it to be an array:

```
personArr  = [
    { key: "a1", value: "catname", type: "cat" },
    { key: "a2", value: "catname2", type: "cat" },
    { key: "a3", value: "somedog", type: "dog" },
    { key: "a4", value: "horsename", type : "horse" }
];
```

Please note that each key: value needs separated comma (you missed it sometimes). In addition, you forgot to close `"horse` with `"`

In declaration of a function, you don't pass parameter, just declare them:

```
filterAndCheckMatchedObj(animalType, personObj) {
    const filteredParsonArr = personArr.filter(person => person.type === animalType);
}
```

Now you need any relation between personArr to personObj.

```
var personObj = { catname: "somecat",
                   catname2: "somecat",
                   dogname: "ruff",
                   horsename: "sam"
                 };
```

Last thing:

I suggest you to change variables names.
It doesn't make sense that you have personArr and his objects describe animals.

To sum up:

```js
const personArr  = [
    { key: "a1", value: "catname", type: "cat" },
    { key: "a2", value: "catname2", type: "cat" },
    { key: "a3", value: "somedog", type: "dog" },
    { key: "a4", value: "horsename", type : "horse" }
];
const personObj  = { catname: "somecat" ,catname2: "somecat", dogname: "ruff", horsename: "sam"}


function filterAndCheckMatchedObj(animalType, personObj) {
    return personArr.some(animal => animal.type === animalType && 
                                   (animal.value in personObj)
                         );

}

alert(filterAndCheckMatchedObj('cat', personObj)); // true
alert(filterAndCheckMatchedObj('fish', personObj)); // false
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to achieve here. But from what I understand, you:

1. Want to filter the `personArr` for the `type`.
2. Then you want to check if any of the `key` in the `personObj` matches any of the `values` of the key `value` in the filtered `personArr`.
3. Return `true` in this case. Else return `false`.

So give this a try:

```js
var personObj = {
  catname: "somecat",
  catname2: "somecat",
  dogname: "ruff",
  horsename: "sam"
};

var personArr = [
  { "key": "a1", "value": "catname", "type": "cat" }, 
  { "key": "a2", "value": "catname2", "type": "cat" }, 
  { "key": "a3", "value": "somedog", "type": "dog" }, 
  { "key": "a4", "value": "horsename", "type": "horse" }
];

function find(type, personObj) {
  var filteredArray = personArr.filter(item => item.type === type);
  var objectKeys = Object.keys(personObj);
  var arrayValues = filteredArray.map(item => item.value);
  return objectKeys.filter(element => arrayValues.includes(element)).length > 0;
}

console.log(find('cat', personObj))
```